# Access local file from browser using jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, file, browser

I'm trying to access local file from Browser. The file is located in Client Computer under C drive.

I tried different solution but all gave me error Access is denied.

I know that almost all browsers have disabled this functionality, but isn't there any setting we can do in browser or in client computer to make it work.

Someone told me to install browser extension to make it work, but I don't know how to do that.

```
  try {
                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                        var lines = xmlhttp.responseText;    //*here we get all lines from text file*
                        alert(lines);
                    }
                }

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "file:///E:\file.txt", true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, for security reasons you cannot automatically load a file from the user's Hard Drive.

What you can do is create an `<input name="myFile" type="file">` and make the user manually select the file you need. This is the only way